# Error while trying to add an element to a listModel

Tags: java, awt, jlist, defaultlistmodel

for some reason when i try to add an element to a `ListModel`, I keep getting this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1

This is the block of code in which it happens:

```
if (shoppingCart.getModel().getSize()  > 0)
{
        for (int i = 0; i <= shoppingCart.getModel().getSize();i++)
        {
            Object a = shoppingCart.getModel().getElementAt(i);
            System.out.println(a.toString()); // this is to test if it gets the right value
                                              // it does.
            booksToAdd.addElement(a.toString()); //but here it cannot add it

        }

}
```

I don't understand what is wrong.  I tried to do research and it came up with something along the lines of its out of bounds for an array, but I do not know what an array has to do with this.

Comment: check list `booksToAdd`

Answer (score 0):

Since `getSize` is the number of elements and `i` is the index, if you allow `i` to go all the way up to the size you are going to be looking for one more element then you have in your array/list (indexes start at zero where a count would start at 1)

You should instead have

`for (int i = 0; i < shoppingCart.getModel().getSize();i++)`

and not       `i <= shoppingCart.getModel().getSize()`

Comment: Wow... Thanks.  I cannot believe I made that mistake.  I was really confused why that did not work.  Thought it was for all the wrong reasons.

Comment: No worries, Im sure everyone does it now and then!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely throwing the error in the initial check for shoppingCart.getModel().getSize().

You can use the following as your initial check forthe existence of list items:

```
if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(shoppingCart.getModel())
```